# Nodejs Mocha Chai Expect to have one key OR another

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I tried to google it, but I did not find the answer. I have a function that generates an object that could have one of two keys (let's say key 'a' and key 'b'). I 'expect' that this object contain only ONE of the two key, not both and not certainly not none. The object must contain key 'a' OR 'b'.

How to create this "OR" in Chai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chai does not have anything dedicated to this niche case.

The solution is to do the legwork yourself and then use `assert.isTrue()` or equivalent.

```
const
    hasProp = Object.hasOwnProperty,
    hasA = hasProp.call(myObject, 'a'),
    hasB = hasProp.call(myObject, 'b'),
    hasOne = hasA || hasB,
    hasBoth = hasA && hasB;

assert.isTrue(
    hasOne && !hasBoth,
    'myObject must contain only one of a or b'
);
```

Note that I have optimized for readability and extensibility there. If you wanted to micro-optimize for performance and will only ever have two keys, this will work without the `hasOne` and `hasBoth` constants.

```
assert.isTrue(
    hasA ? !hasB : hasB,
    'myObject must contain only one of a or b'
);
```

Comment: It would certainly be a nice feature for chai. Anyway, thanks for the solution.

Comment: I agree. Keith Amus - Chai's maintainer - is a very nice guy and I suspect he would be open to this. Although he might ask you to submit the patch to make it happen. https://github.com/chaijs/chai